# Does every totally ordered set has an upper bound?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I'm studying Set theory using Halmos's book.

I'm wondering whether it is true to state that "Every totally ordered set has an upper bound" (no matter it is finite or infinite) ?

My intuition is that since the set $S$ is totally ordered, then 2 arbitrary elements $x$ and $y$ are comparable, say $x \leq y$, then we compare $x$ with $x_1$, $y$ with $y_1$, $x$ with $y_1$, $y$ with $x_1$ to find the correct order of the extension. If we do it ad infinitum, we can eventually order the set $S$, and find the upper bound of it. But I was not able to give a rigorous proof.

Can you please tell me if the statement is correct ? If not can you please give me an example in case it fails ? or eventually a sketch of proof it is true.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the upper bound of the (totally ordered) set or natural numbers?

Comment: You're mistaken in  this case, but yout intuituion isn't a bad one. It's similar to what underlies _Zorn's lemma_: if every totally-ordered subset of $S$ _does_ have an upper bound, then $S$ has a maximal element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every totally ordered set has a maximum element (which is what I assume you mean by “has an upper bound”). Consider, for instance, the natural numbers under their usual order. However, every non-empty *finite* totally ordered set has a maximum element. Try proving this by induction on the size of the set, and then try seeing why this kind of reasoning cannot be extended to be the infinite case.

Comment: ah great, you are right, thanks!!!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: No problem! I should also point out that you might be slightly misusing terminology. If you look at Halmos' book, you will see that the definition of an upper bound really involves two sets: a partially ordered set $X$ (which might happen to also be totally ordered), and a subset $E$ of $X$. The definition of "upper bound" is given for the set $E$.

Comment: Here, I'm assuming that you intended $E=X$, so that in my example, we are considering the natural numbers as a subset of ... the natural numbers. It would be more standard to call an upper bound of $\mathbb N$ the "maximum element of $\mathbb N$" – although no such element exists!

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: In other words, it does not really make sense to ask whether a set $E$ is bounded above. You need to specify the partially ordered set that $E$ is considered to be a subset of. For instance, $\mathbb N$ is not bounded above when considered as a subset of $\mathbb N$, but it *is* when considered as a subset of $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, say. (If I were to be really pedantic, then I would also specify the orderings that $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ are equipped with, but without further context, they are assumed to be the “usual” ones.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your clarification! in the case of $N$ which is a subset of $R$ (without $-\infty$ and $\infty$, is $N$ still bounded above ? I think not, right ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: When considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$, the natural numbers are not bounded above because it is *not the case* that there exists an $a\in\mathbb R$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb N$, we have $n\le a$. In other words, for all $a\in\mathbb R$ there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>a$. This is a corollary of the [Archimedean property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property) of $\mathbb R$, which you might have met before in a real analysis course.

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge: Did you give the induction proof a go? If you post it here, or in the body of your original question, I can give you feedback for it.